# Why is data within a memory proxy marked as dirty?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I've a store that is using a memory proxy. The store get it's data by calling the `loadRawData` method. I now make some changes to this data using roweditor & rowaction which result in dirty records which seems to be a correct behavior but this store will never be able to sync any data so why are all cells marked with this red triangle?

I think I must oversee something here. How can I spare these trinangels without loosing the track on modified fields?

I am using ExtJS 4.2.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want the little red triangles on your grid, you can set the following in the viewConfig.

```
markDirty: false
```

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.view.Table-cfg-markDirty

Comment: This is the correct answer. It removes the red triangles without interfering with record data.

Comment: @Eric sorry I just have overseen LUKE's answer

Answer (score 2):

> As LUKE already answered the Question I will add just some additional information about the dirty flag of a record

---

> **Note**: the [`dirty`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/source/Model.html#Ext-data-Model-property-dirty)  flag is marked as **readonly** and this is for a reason.

Here is at least one reason:

> The time [`set()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/source/Model.html#Ext-data-Model-method-set) finishes the record has already published the
>   changes to the store(s) which in the same time fires the [`update`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-event-update) event for
>   the modified data.

So changing the [`dirty`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/source/Model.html#Ext-data-Model-property-dirty) flag will have no affect because it happens after all this! So the record will be already marked as dirty e.g. the grid will have already marked all changed columns with the red triangle.

---

To prevent the record from setting it's [`dirty`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/source/Model.html#Ext-data-Model-property-dirty) flag use a [`beginEdit()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/source/Model.html#Ext-data-Model-method-beginEdit) / [`endEdit()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/source/Model.html#Ext-data-Model-method-endEdit) block and don't use set because [`set()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/source/Model.html#Ext-data-Model-method-set) will always set dirty the flag.

Here is a example which inverts a boolean and **don't** affect the `dirty` flag

```
record.beginEdit();
record.data.active = !rec.data.active;
record.endEdit();
```

Comment: This is a vast over-complication, why is it the accepted answer?

Comment: @Reimius 1. I just want to add some additional information about the dirty flag. That is why I started my answer with '**Note**' and I mentioned at no time that this should be done just to prevent the red triangle. Yes, this time I forget to start with 'as a additional information...' but I thought it was obvious that LUKE already answered the question. 2. I will add this information now 3. It was not up to me to accept. I just answer to a answered question if I think the information is worth doing so.

Comment: I don't have a problem with your answer being here, it's just that it's not the answer to the question and I am confused as to why it was accepted as correct when it doesn't address the problem that the asker was trying to resolve.  It's analogue to someone asking how to mask a panel and then the answerer explaining how html is modified when someone uses the function, without telling them which function to call to do it.

Comment: @Reimius I think I understood that but you know, you should ask this question to seba and I think he will only get noticed if you comment one of his posts or address him.

Comment: @Reimius sorry I just have overseen LUKE's answer